# Is there any slang word for somebody who doesn't show up for a date?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Is there any slang word that describes somebody who doesn't show up when you date him?

Comment: A no-show (if you want to dampen the effect of retelling the tale of being *stood up*)

Comment: Are you looking for a word to describe the person who didn't show up, or the act of waiting for someone who doesn't show up?

Comment: "A slang" is a language. What you are looking for "a slang *word*", or simply "slang", uncountable, no article.

Comment: Dumped! \*baddum-tsh\*

Comment: if he never shows up, you actually haven't dated him yet.

Comment: I would call him a "jerk."

Answer (score 14):

> No-show.

Although the correct answer for the action is definitely "stand up".

> I can't believe it, he stood me up.

Comment: But only for *no-show*, not *stand-up*.

Comment: Only for _stand-up_, not _no-show_.

Comment: This isn't correct, RAY is asking for a slang term for the person, not the action. "He's a stand up" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hmm ... he often makes dates and does not show up ... he's a *stand-up guy*...

Comment: @LittleBigBot "He's a stand-up" makes perfect sense; it just has a different meaning from the one intended...

Comment: @GEdgar ["Stand-up guy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stand+up+guy%22&oq=%22stand+up+guy%22) means that the guy is dependable, reliable, of good character, etc. It's *not* the kind of guy who'd have stood up his date.

Comment: I was stood up in college by a boy named Joseph. He has ever after been referred to as "No Show Joe."

Answer (score 5):

The most common slang term I've heard for this is [*stood up*](http://www.cnn.com/2010/LIVING/11/29/tf.dealing.being.stood.up/). In *5 stages of dealing with being stood up* (CNN), the opening lines are:

> Nobody likes to get stood up! But it does happen. And if you date long enough, it's bound to happen. It's so embarrassing. You get left at a restaurant, the dude never shows, the man of your dreams just doesn't call.

Comment: And to derive a noun from that, you can call him either a _stand-up_ (rare, in my experience), a _stand-upper_, or a _stander-upper_. All three are quite slangy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm okay with the other two, but I wouldn't call him or her a *stand-up* unless she or he were very funny.

Comment: @bib I have heard it used to mean someone who stands people up, but only rarely. For some reason, I can't help but think of it as being more habitual, a la “He's such a stand-up, always blowing his friends off when he's supposed to be meeting with them”. (Very different, of course, from calling him a real stand-up kind of guy!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Probably the most common use of *stand-up* (at least in the US) is to refer to a *stand-up comic*.

Comment: @bib Yes, that's the primary meaning of _stand-up_ as a noun and, I suspect, the reason it's not commonly used for a stander-upper.

Comment: I think you'd get some odd looks if you tried using any of the nouns in the first comment (brit here). If someone said "He's a stand-up", first I'd assume a comic, and if that was clearly not the case then I'd assume it was a misuse of the phrase "a stand up guy" ([evidently slang](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stand+Up+Guy)) and a stand up guy wouldn't be standing anyone up..

Comment: LoL, it's @Janus Bahs Jacquet doin' the stand-up!

Answer (score 3):

I belive that the correct term here would be `flaker`.

> Someone who does not show up when they had previously stated they
>   will. Also, someone who has no intention of showing up, but acts like
>   they will or want to show up only to mess with your feelings.

ex:

> Tim is such a flaker. I can't believe that he bailed out the very last
>   minute! I'm definitely not inviting him to hang out next time.

source: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flaker

Comment: Calling someone a `flake` is also appropriate: "Jack is such a flake."

Comment: Please note that quoting text without citing where you’re quoting from is tantamount to plagiarism and will be deleted on sight by the mods. You should add a link to the Urban Dictionary entries you have cited here.

Comment: @Little A flake is more general to me (and I see UD agrees): it’s someone who’s just generally unreliable or muddles his way through life in a bit of a wishy-washy, willy-nilly fashion and leads a flaky existence. A flake is quite likely to stand you up, but someone who stands you up is not necessarily a flake.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, that's true, it'd require context.

Answer (score 0):

[To blow somebody off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+off):

> to ignore someone or *something; to skip an appointment with someone;* to not attend something where one is expected. He decided to sleep in and blow this class off. It wasn't right for you to just blow off an old friend the way you did.

Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: That also means _fellatio_ in BrE; use with caution.

Comment: Sure, that is probably the origin of the idiom:))

Answer (score 0):

I call no-shows a 'fluff' or a 'fluffer' - a flakey individual who is all puff and no follow through, i.e. a 'fluff' is a mocker of other people's time.

Comment: Have you any sources supporting the use of this term by others?

Answer (score -1):

A slang term for not showing up that my friends and I use is *fader*.

*Fader* is a general term and isn’t necessarily related to a date.

Example:

> Charles didn’t show up again — could he be any more of a fader?

Comment: Is this a commonly used word, or is it something that **only** you and your friends use?

Comment: @Doc It appears [in urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fader) FWIW

Comment: I have heard it used outside of my friend group.
Mostly in informal settings, but I have also heard it at work (I worked in a relaxed environment).

Comment: @MartinSmith, thank you, I should probably have referenced that to avoid that negative vote.